# Cypress Chrome Browser not available

Tags: cypress, e2e-testing

When I run Cypress for E2E tests on my machine, I don't see Chrom browser, I only see Edge, Electron and Firefox browsers as you see in the screenshot.

Any idea how do I add Chrome to the list of the browsers ? I have tried a lot of things but nothing works.

Comment: Have you installed Chrome on your OS?

Comment: Yes I have install it and I am using it as the main browser